# numpy alternative for C++: linear algebra / FFT / numeric goodies?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I've been using python + numpy for a while, and got familiarized (and charmed) with it. Now, I need to do some calculations using C++, and was looking for a nice library to do numerical stuff fast and easy (TM :P). I've been looking around and I found several options:

- GSL
- Eigen
- NT2
- Boost uBlast

As understanding and getting use to a new library is quite an effort, I was wondering if the SO folks could give comments on this. Right now I would need basic FFT and SVD decomposition, but goodies like slicing of arrays, vectorization of functions and the like would be much appreciated.

What are your thoughts in this aspect?

Comment: Community wiki?  Also: I recommend `Boost.uBLAS`, but I'm biased towards Boost.

Comment: Aren't such questions better off at scicomp.stackexchange.com ?